# Kendo UI Grid Export CSV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

please help me my probs,am using kendo ui grid in my webapp & trying to grid data export into EXcel and CSV format. Code Works good in Chrome and files are downloading, but in Fire Fox its open a new window show the grid details in url and says bad request,

//code is

```
$("#exportcsv").click(function (e) {
               debugger
               var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

               var filteredDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   data: dataSource.data(),
                   filter: dataSource.filter()
               });

               filteredDataSource.read();
               var data = filteredDataSource.view();

               //start with the desired column headers here
               var result = "\"ID\",\"EID\",\"Name\",\"Company Name\",\"Salary\",\"DID\",\"Date Of Join\"";

               //each column will need to be called using the field name in the data source
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                   result += "\n";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].id + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].EID + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].EName + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].CName + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].Salary + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].DID + "\",";

                   result += "\"" + data[i].DOJ + "\",";
               }





               if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
                   //Internet Explorer
                   window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv');
               }

               else if (window.webkitURL != null) {

                       //Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
                       var a = document.createElement('a');
                       result = encodeURIComponent(result);
                       a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + result;
                       a.download = 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv';
                       a.click();
                   }
               else {
                   //Everything Else
                   window.open(result);
               }
               e.preventDefault();
           });
```

//below code is not working in firefox browser  else if

```
 (window.webkitURL != null) {

                        //Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                        result = encodeURIComponent(result);
                        a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + result;
                        a.download = 'ExportedKendoGrid.csv';
                        a.click();
                    }
```